# How to configure IIS for sending compressed JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.Net 2.0 website hosted in `IIS6`. It has `webmethod` defined in code-behind classes. These webmethods are accessed by `jQuery Ajax`.

Now, when I host the website in a `gzip` enabled website, we are getting `content-length` as zero in the client. Without compression the website works fine.

I read in the article [Enabling dynamic compression (gzip, deflate)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx) about `ApplicationHost.config` and following configuration – but it is for `IIS7`.

[image]

What is the command / tool / configuration to enable `JSON` compression in **IIS6**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in IIS6, compression was determined by its metabase and not through ASP.NET configuration, another difference is that it was by file extensions and not mime types.

You can read about it in [Using HTTP Compression for Faster Downloads (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true)